# How to build animation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, webkit

I have 3 yellow bars. The bar should come from out of my boundary box to inside. While the yellow box enter in to site, it should delay each other 3sec. And I like to build this animation using Webkit-transition. I know I can use javascript to implement it.

What is best way to do this?

Comment: Any links where we could see what you're trying to do? Do you allow the use of JavaScript libraries like jQuery to make it easy on yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines?

http://jsfiddle.net/N82Kc/

It doesn't use WebKit transform so it works in all browsers. Depends what your users need.

Comment: what you given this example is 100% correct. but my situation i need to do this by javascript. is it possible. because i am developing this project for iPad. so we can include javascript+webkit. any idea?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: But this is JavaScript. jQuery is still JavaScript. If you need some more lightweight animation you should either take out the things you need or search the web for some super simple animation stuff. But you can run jQuery on your iPhone just as well.